# jquery - get attribute of multidimensional named input

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, pattern-matching

I have the following input field, and I'm trying to figure out how to increment the value of a specific bracketed value...

How would I go about incrementing a particular bracketed value (i.e., title[0][subtitle][3] becomes title[0][subtitle][4])?

I've managed to partially get it working by hardcoding a value... The code below essentially does what I want, except that I can't figure out how to store and increment that particular value dynamically...

(also posted on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/492bD/ )...

```
<input type="text" class="form-text" value="" name="title[0][subtitle][0]">
<button id="clickme">Click me</button>
​
$('#clickme').live('click', function() { 
var lastSubTitle = $('input.form-text').attr('name');
var newSubTitle = lastSubTitle.replace(/^(.*\[[0-9]+\].*)(\[[0-9]+\])(.*)$/, '$1[20]$3');
alert(newSubTitle);
});
```

Comment: which value do you want to store?

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason you don't want to just use two (or more) properties and increment them separately?

```
<input type="text" class="form-text" value="" data-title="0" data-subtitle="0">
<button id="clickme">Click me</button>
​
$('#clickme').live('click', function() {
    var formText$ = $('input.form-text');
    formText$.attr('data-subtitle', +formText$.attr('data-subtitle') + 1); 
    alert(formText$.attr('data-subtitle'));
});​
```

If you need the `name` to have the value in that particular format, you can then just set the `name` property after incrementing the data.

```
formText$.attr('name', 'title[' + formText$.attr('data-title') +
                       '][subtitle][' + formText$.attr('data-subtitle') + ']');
```

You can see it at http://jsfiddle.net/tMcxH/1/.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without referring to complex regex, this is a solution done with string functions:

```
lastSubTitle = "title[0][subtitle][0]";
var n = lastSubTitle.substr(0, lastSubTitle.length -1);
var f = n.substr(n.lastIndexOf('[')+1);
var value = parseInt(f,10);
value++;
lastSubTitle = lastSubTitle.substr(0, n.lastIndexOf('[')+1) + value + ']';

alert(lastSubTitle); // alerts "title[0][subtitle][1]"
```

that should do it.